# how to get js var data from GDownloadUrl callback?

Tags: javascript, selenium, callback

Now, I have tried to get some data from crawling website.

The target website provides current status of bicycle stations using google map.

```
GDownloadUrl("/mapAction.do?process=statusMapView", function(data, responseCode) {

        var jsonData = eval("(" + data + ")");
        //alert(jsonData.centerLat);
        var length = jsonData.markers.length;
        //if (length > 100) length = 100;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(jsonData.markers[i].lat), parseFloat(jsonData.markers[i].lng));
            var name = jsonData.markers[i].name;
            var cntRackTotal = jsonData.markers[i].cntRackTotal;
            var cntRentable = jsonData.markers[i].cntRentable;
            var cntLockOff = jsonData.markers[i].cntLockOff;
            var cntPrtRack = jsonData.markers[i].cntPrtRack;
            var percent = jsonData.markers[i].percent;
            var imgFile = jsonData.markers[i].imgFile;
            var number = jsonData.markers[i].kiosk_no;

            //map.addOverlay(createMarker(number, point, name, cntRackTotal, cntRentable, cntLockOff, cntPrtRack, percent, imgFile ));


        }
    });
```

This JS source code is used on target website. In GDownloadUrl callback function, the parameter "data" contains current status of bicycle stations. And I want to get data.
Now, I tried using python selenium and execute_script().

```
    jsSourcecode = ("var strData;"+
    "strData = GDownloadUrl('/mapAction.do?process=statusMapView',"+
    " function(data, responseCode) {return data;}); return strData;")

data = driver.execute_script(jsSourcecode)
```

this source code is that I used to get data. I expected data on callback would be stored on var strData and the return value of execute_script() would be the data. but the return value is just "True".

I have little knowledge about js.. How can I get the data? Please help

Answer (score 0):

The function you are calling is asynchronous and requires a callback function as argument.

Use `execute_async_script` and provide the callback present in the last argument:

```
data, status = driver.execute_async_script("""
  var callback = arguments[0];
  window.GDownloadUrl('/mapAction.do?process=statusMapView', function(data, status){
    callback([data, status]);
  });
  """)
```